# java: copy a java class file to custom package [copyright issues?]

Tags: java, documentation

Please note that this question is not about coding

I have a package named `com.java.examples` where I have my java files.

I like to copy **all** the contents from `LinkedBlockingQueue.class` to a file so that others can view the documentation. *[Let's not bring online documentation and other sources like peeping into the `rt.jar`, into the picture]*

My question is , if I do that, will it become a *copyright* issue, as `LinkedBlockingQueue` will be packaged under a new package `com.java.examples` ?

Update:

In the copyright file under jdk/jre , there is a statement

> "Reverse engineering, disassembly, or decompilation of this software,
>   unless required by law for interoperability, is prohibited."

Does my scenario falls under this?

Comment: Read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html

Comment: what I understood is LinkedBlockingQueue should not be modified and should be used only to run programs. But what about copying it to a different file say text file. Also, please see my update

Comment: While im not a lawyer, and this may be some sorta grey area, I suspect the answer lies in section D of the SUPPLEMENTAL LICENSE TERMS section, specifically this line : "Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without fees to reproduce and distribute those files specifically identified as redistributable in the README File ("Redistributables") provided that: (i) you distribute the Redistributables complete and unmodified, and only bundled as part of Programs..." Also see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/readme142u19-429197.html

Comment: Can you post your comments as seperate answer, and I'll close it

Comment: Moved them to an answer, though something weird happened to the links.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964) You may be able to get help on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com), but [**read their faq carefully** before proceeding](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic). Legal questions may be asked on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: please feel free to close or delete or move it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html)

While im not a lawyer, and this may be some sorta grey area, I suspect the answer lies in section D of the SUPPLEMENTAL LICENSE TERMS section, specifically this line : "Oracle grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable, limited license without fees to reproduce and distribute those files specifically identified as redistributable in the README File ("Redistributables") provided that: (i) you distribute the Redistributables complete and unmodified, and only bundled as part of Programs..."

Also see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8-readme-2095712.html#redistribution

Comment: I edited fixing the broken links

Answer (score 1):

It would be a copyright violation if you're not the author of LinkedBlockingQueue or you don't have the permission of the copyright holder. There is an implicit copyright on anything whether there is a copyright statement or not.

Comment: Can you cite a source?

Comment: Thank you, although you didn't cite the source.